# How can I generate a sequence number in a empty table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a query that can generate the latest sequence number +1 to the new record in sql server.

let ignore the insert part first, I write a query like this:

```
SELECT 'asdf' AS col1, CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT pk_sales_inv_no FROM salesInvoice WHERE pk_sales_inv_no LIKE 'Q-ARF2206-%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS EXPR1
```

It looks fine, when the record with same prefix exists, It return 1, else 0.
[image]

Because I have to process the current latest sequence number in the true value part, so I change my query with this to get the pk_sales_inv_no for the true part processing.

```
SELECT TOP (1) 'asdf' AS col1, CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT pk_sales_inv_no FROM salesInvoice WHERE pk_sales_inv_no LIKE 'Q-ARF2206-%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS EXPR1 FROM salesInvoice WHERE (pk_sales_inv_no LIKE 'Q-ARF2206-%') ORDER BY pk_sales_inv_no DESC
```

Then problem happens, because the select result is totally empty, so It doesn't return the 1 or 0.

How can I improve it to work out with a empty select result.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple scalar udf, if you need it in JOIN adapt it as a table value function.

I doubt that this is what you need, I think you want to get the number after the 2nd dash

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.udf_lastSequence') IS NOT NULL
   DROP FUNCTION dbo.udf_lastSequence
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_lastSequence (@invNo varchar(100))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @lastInvNo VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @search VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @result int

    SET @result = 0
    SET @search = CONCAT(@invNo, '%');

    SELECT TOP 1 @lastInvNo = pk_sales_inv_no
    FROM salesInvoice 
    WHERE (pk_sales_inv_no LIKE @search)
    ORDER BY pk_sales_inv_no DESC

    IF @lastInvNo IS NOT NULL
        SET @result = CAST(REPLACE(@lastInvNo, @invNo, '') AS INT); 

    return @result
END
GO
```

Try it with `SELECT dbo.udf_lastSequence('Q-ARF2206-')` **WITHOUT** the final *%* charter

Comment: Is there any difference if I not doing it in a single query?

Comment: Within a single query, you have the problem of the empty result and then is not optimized, you can try to execute the begin..end part and your query then compare the execution plans.